# Responsive canvas keeping given aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, css, angular, canvas, responsive-design

I'm developing a drawing app, and I've encountered a problem which I have been trying to solve but I haven't found a reliable solution yet:

Sketches have an original resolution of 1280 x 720, and I would like to **resize the canvas when the page is opened to the maximum size possible (given the screen dimensions minus a toolbar I have put on the upper side of the page) keeping the 1280 x 720 aspect ratio**. 
The canvas needs to be centered in the screen and black stripes will cover the rest: when the the browser window dimensions relation is less than the sketch original w/h relation there will be horizontal black stripes (fig [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46qyq.png)), and when it is bigger, vertical black stripes (fig [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFoqk.png)).

I've tried using javascript applying to the canvas the offsetWidth and offsetHeight of a div containing an auxiliar invisible image which I generate programatically with the original sketch dimensions, but doesn't seem to be a robust way to do this. Most of the time the offset properties aren't ready when the page is loaded and I have to wait for them using a timer (or mutation observers).

Some images of what I'm trying to do:

I've spend much time on this little thing and is driving me crazy, because every solution I found is way too hacky or unreliable. Any help will be very appreciated.

I'm using Angular + Ionic 4.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to dynamically change the size of your canvas based on how big the window is. The one stipulation is that it must maintain the 1280 x 720 (1:0.5625) ratio.

I'm going to attempt to provide a solution that will also listen for resizing of the window *after* it's been loaded. Keep in mind that this means you'll need to redraw everything on the canvas from there.

## HTML

```
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

## CSS

```
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

## JavaScript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

startListening();

function startListening() {
  // resize the canvas every time the window is adjusted
  window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
  // manually call the resizeCanvas() function as the window loads with it's starting dimensions (before a resize has happened)
  resizeCanvas();
}

function resizeCanvas() {
  // if the canvas height isn't maxed out, match it to the width of the page at the correct aspect ration (1:0.5625)
  if(canvas.height < window.innerHeight){
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = canvas.width * 0.5625;
  }
  
  // if the canvas height is maxed out, stop widening the canvas and lock the canvas height at 0.5625 of that locked height
  if(canvas.height >= window.innerHeight){
    canvas.height = canvas.width * 0.5625;
  }
  
  // lastly, if we are shrinking the width back down, readjust both the width and height to match
  if(canvas.width > window.innerWidth){
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = canvas.width * 0.5625;
  }
  // redraw the canvas with our newly calculated dimensions
  redraw();
}

function redraw() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
  // Draw the canvas in the center of the screen at the height and width calculated above in the resizeCanvas() function
  ctx.fillRect((window.innerWidth - canvas.width) / 2, (window.innerHeight - canvas.height) / 2, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```